# Zend 2 - User session does not work

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I'm having difficulty reading logged user's session in user model.

When retrieve user data from any other model it works perfectly.

MODULE.PHP

```
'session' => function ($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('config');
                if (isset($config['session'])) {
                    $session = $config['session']['config']['options']['name'];

                    //Various Session options
                    $manager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager();                        

                     if(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'APPLICATION_ENV') === 'production'){

                        $manager->getConfig()
                                ->setCookieHttpOnly(true)
                                ->setCookieSecure(false);
                        $manager->start();

                    }

                    return new Session($session);
                }
            },
```

BaseTable.php

```
    public function getIdentity($property = null) {
    $storage = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('session');

    if (!$storage) {
        return false;
    }

    $data = $storage->read();

    if ($property && isset($data[$property])) {
        return $data[$property];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

When i call getIdentity function where tb_usuario instantiated I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\sigaAvaliacoes\module\application\src\Application\Model\BaseTable.php
>   on line 73

Sorry my english, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i found the problem, in Module.php i not instance serviceLocator:

```
'Usuario' => function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = new TableGateway('tb_usuario', $sm->get('db_adapter_main'));
                return new Model\Usuario($tableGateway);
            },
```

Now work:

```
'Usuario' => function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = new TableGateway('tb_usuario', $sm->get('db_adapter_main'));
                $updates = new Model\Usuario($tableGateway);
                $updates->setServiceLocator($sm);
                return $updates;
            },
```

Thanks =D